# Change parametr in function depending from i in a loop

Tags: javascript, xml

How to change getProjectssexy(1) to i number(depending from tmpArray.length)
for each element i need  getProjectssexy(0), getProjectssexy(1), and so on

```
  $('allarray', data).each(function(){
            tmpArray = $('array', this).toArray();
                var table = document.getElementById("tleft");
                table.innerHTML = "";
                for(i =0; i<tmpArray.length; i++) {
                    table.innerHTML += "<div class='two'>" +
                    "<a href='#' onclick='getProjectssexy(1 - need to change i for every loop)'>" +
                    tmpArray[i].getAttribute("id") + "</a>" +"</div>" + "</br>";
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to store it somewhere on the element. You can use the [html5 data-*](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) attributes to store it and [jQuery .data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to retrieve it.

```
$('allarray', data).each(function(){
        tmpArray = $('array', this).toArray();
            var table = document.getElementById("tleft");
            table.innerHTML = "";
            for(i =0; i<tmpArray.length; i++) {
                table.innerHTML += "<div class='two'>" +
                "<a href='#' data-i='" + i + "' onclick='getProjectssexy(this)'>" +
                tmpArray[i].getAttribute("id") + "</a>" +"</div>" + "</br>";
            }
        });

function getProjectssexy(elem) {
    var i = $(elem).data('i');
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic solution it's

```
$('allarray', data).each(function(){
            tmpArray = $('array', this).toArray();
                var table = document.getElementById("tleft");
                table.innerHTML = "";
                for(i =0; i<tmpArray.length; i++) {
                    table.innerHTML += "<div class='two'>" +
                    "<a href='#' onclick='getProjectssexy("+i+")'>" +
                    tmpArray[i].getAttribute("id") + "</a>" +"</div>" + "</br>";
                }
            });
```